# Mouseenter and mouseleave change for mobile and tablet

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, mouseevent

How to change mouseenter and mouseleave to working with click?
I have images and on click show another inside.
How to fix mouseleave, here is code in Javascript:

```
$("div.mitarbeiterfoto")
    .mouseenter(function() { 
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var idInfo = $(this).attr("id").substr(5);
            ($(this).find('img').css('display', 'none'));
            ($('#' + id + '_o').css('display', 'block'));
            showInfo(idInfo);
    })

    .mouseleave(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var idInfo = $(this).attr("id").substr(5);
            ($(this).find('img').css('display', 'block'));
            ($('#' + id + '_o').css('display', 'none'));
            hideInfo(idInfo);
    });
```

Please i need help!

Comment: Can you please put a fiddle?

Comment: Why not trigger events on click too?

Comment: How do you distinguish between tablet/mobile and desktop?

Answer (score -1):

Assigning events like this would work

```
$('.mitarbeiterfoto').on('mouseenter', function () {
       var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var idInfo = $(this).attr("id").substr(5);
            ($(this).find('img').css('display', 'none'));
            ($('#' + id + '_o').css('display', 'block'));
            showInfo(idInfo);
});

$('.mitarbeiterfoto').on('mouseleave', function () {
       var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var idInfo = $(this).attr("id").substr(5);
        ($(this).find('img').css('display', 'block'));
        ($('#' + id + '_o').css('display', 'none'));
        hideInfo(idInfo);
});


$('.mitarbeiterfoto').on('click', function () {
    //click
});
```